# android studio installation without a component

Tags: java, android-studio

I've installed android studio with openjdk instead oracle jdk. In installation process
doesn't appear android SDK as a common component. Is this usual?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks right. Same installer when I installer android studio a month ago.

Edit:
I assume you are talking about jdk not being a component, but it looks the same.

Comment: thanks. I refer jdk like java development kit not sdk component.

Comment: can you mark my answer as the correct one, just click on the check mark